# Prove the sum of squares of partitions smaller than gap times the length of the interval

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $P=\{x_0, \ldots, x_N\}$  be any partition of some $[a, b]$.
 Prove that
$\sum_{n=1}^N |x_n -x_{n-1}|^2 \leq |b-a|\, \mathrm{gap}( P )$

I expanded both sides but still have no ideas.

Comment: What is your gap$(P)$?

Comment: Is $x_i < x_{i+1}$ for all $i$?

Comment: gap P = max$[x_i-x_{i-1}]$

Comment: No, it could be any partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
 |x_n -x_{n-1}|^2= |x_n -x_{n-1}|\, |x_n -x_{n-1}|\le\operatorname{gap}(P)|x_n -x_{n-1}|=\operatorname{gap}(P)(x_n -x_{n-1}).
$$

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I see it!